# Jquery Ajax Sends same value for each new request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, performance

I am working on a restaurant website. I have a PHP page on which I am displaying restaurant menu categories into a list box.

When a specific category is selected, I am loading menu items of the selected category using jquery and ajax. Below is the jquery code

```
$("#mlist").change(function(){
   var v = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
   var u = $(this).children(":selected").attr("name");
   //alert(u);
    $.ajax({
            url:'menuitems.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{mid:v,cid:u},
            success:function(response){
                var msg =response;

                $("#itembox").html(msg);
            }
        });
});
```

Call is always successful and the next page gets loaded. In the requested page, I am displaying menuitem-id, menuitem-name, a text box for quantity and a check box for selection. Everything is perfectly good. PHP code is below

```
$mid=$_GET['mid'];
$cid=$_GET['cid'];
$result2 = oci_parse($gerp,"SELECT * FROM ITEM where ITEM_TYPE_ID=".$cid." AND CLS_ID=".$mid."AND STATUS = 'A' ");
         oci_execute($result2);
         $line=1;
         while($row_data2 = oci_fetch_array($result2,OCI_BOTH)){

        echo"<div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-btn'>";
        echo"<div class='col-xs-6'><button type=button class='btn btn-danger' style='width:400px' id=".$row_data2['ITEM_ID'].">".$row_data2['ITEM_NAME']."</button></div></div>";
       echo"<div class='col-xs-3'><font color=black><input type=text style='width:40px' class='input-group.input-group-sm' placeholder=Qty id=qty".$row_data2['ITEM_ID']."></font></div>";
        echo "<div class='col-xs-3'><div class='checkbox'><input type=checkbox id=".$row_data2['ITEM_ID']."></input></div></div></div><br>";            
        $line++;
        }
```

Everything is fine till now, but here comes my problem. when the user clicks the checkbox, I am trying to send the quantity and menu-item-id to another page using jquery/ajax  Below is the jquery code

```
$(".checkbox").on("click",function() { 
  var itemid=$( "input:checked" ).attr('id').trim();
  var x="#qty"+itemid.trim();
  var qty=$(x).val().trim();
   if((itemid!="") && (qty!="")){
  $.ajax({
            url:'addorderitem.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{i:itemid,q:qty},
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
                }
                });
             }
```

Each time the first selected item and its quantity is sent to the next page. For example, if the first selected menu item id is 101 and quantity is 20 it will send 101 and 20 to next page for every other selected item.
Is this some sort of cache problem. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You did not limit your selection to the current `.checkbox` parent, so `$( "input:checked" )` selects the first checked input field in the whole document that it can find.

Comment: As above.  Change `$("input:checked")` to `$(this)`, possibly with an extra check to ensure it's ticked `if (!$(this).is(":checked")) return;`

Comment: freedomn-m Changing $("input:checked") to $(this) gives TypeError $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Comment: Problem solved with the help of this page https://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-the-id-of-the-checkbox-in-onclick